# Creating a timetable from database

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

I have recently had a request to create a pitch booking system for a sports club. Basically the club want the managers of the teams to be able to request a booking for a pitch at what ever time they pick then an admin can confirm / deny.
I'm not completely sure how I should go about it. So far I was thinking of having a table to represent the days and times the pitches are available then another table for the bookings (which would have the start time, finish time and team name). Then I was thinking about retrieving and displaying the data in a table on the webpage.

For the moment my main concern is the data structure. Am I not sure if the approach I have just mentioned is the right way to go. Any help would be very much appreciated.

And finally if at all possible a few hints on how would be best to display the data in my aspx page would also be appreciated.

I know I am probably going to get told off for such a vague question but I would really appreciate a little help/feedback before I continue on.

Thank you all so much for any help you may be able to provide and I look forward to basking in the awesomeness of your suggestions.

Cheers,

Michael.

Comment: Read up on [Normalisation](http://www.studytonight.com/dbms/database-normalization.php) and your data structure should become fairly obvious.  Trying to get a more detailed response in this Q&A format isn't really going to work, especially as we'd essentially be doing your project for you...

Comment: "a few hints on how would be best to display the data in my aspx page would also be appreciated.". Look at using something like this (each pitch would be a "resource" on the left hand side):  https://fullcalendar.io/scheduler/ (free licenses available for non-profit organisations). You can also consider using this for inputting the bookings as well - with a small amount of work you can make areas of the calendar selectable so people can literally drag and drop their desired booking onto the time period.

Comment: as far as data structure goes, at minimum you need tables to represent: pitches, users, bookings (with foreign keys to pitches and users). If you want to have fixed "slots" for booking into (rather than just letting people pick any start/end times they like) you could potentially define these in another table (you could then inject these into the Scheduler plugin to help validate input).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main question is if the times the pitch(es) are useable random, or regular (hope regular).
If regular (like Monday-Saturday 10-18 ... and can be used hourly) then you need a

pitch table : pitch id, name, number ... etc

can_use table : pitch id, day (1-7 or mon-sun), from hour, to hour

used table : pitch id, day, hour (admin checked and ok)

And in your webpage for every pitch (id) a table, columns are days, rows are hours built from a select * from can_use where pitch_id = ... order by day .
How many rows come from the from hour - to hour items.

Fill the web table (for cycle)-

Select * from used where pitch_id = ... order by pitch_id, day, hour

if day and hour match the item from the select, then it is booked (possible to show if admin checked it too) and go to the next item in the select.

If not, it is a bookable item